# putExtra from List into SMS body

Tags: android, list, android-intent

I'm trying to put the contents of List mCartList; into a the sms_body below, eg: Cheeseburger, Hamburger, Fries (so it can be sent through sms). I can pass a string so I know it works. I'm not a programmer at all and it's been a month of me doing trial & error.

Below the activity calls the contents of mCartList into a List so they can be removed. Tell me whatever else you need to help me solve this. Thank you in advance.

```
private ProductAdapter mProductAdapter;
  // This List into the order button below
   private List<Product> mCartList;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shoppingcart);    
    mCartList = ShoppingCartHelper.getCart();
    // Make sure to clear the selections
    for(int i=0; i<mCartList.size(); i++) {
    mCartList.get(i).selected = false;
  }

                     // Create the list
   final ListView listViewCatalog = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewCatalog);
   mProductAdapter = new ProductAdapter(mCartList, getLayoutInflater(), true);
   listViewCatalog.setAdapter(mProductAdapter);
   listViewCatalog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     Product selectedProduct = mCartList.get(position);
     if(selectedProduct.selected == true)
     selectedProduct.selected = false;
 else
     selectedProduct.selected = true;
     mProductAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
   }
 });

      Button orderButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.orderButton);
      orderButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) {

      Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:1234567890");
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
       // The above List<Product> mCartList ia displayed in the window of the app 
      intent.putExtra("sms_body", "mCartList"); // I want the results of List<Product> mCartList to go here - I can not just insert the variable I just get errors and can't compile 
          startActivity(intent); 
   }    
 });        

      Button removeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonRemoveFromCart);
      removeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // Loop through and remove all the products that are selected
            // Loop backwards so that the remove works correctly

             for(int i=mCartList.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
               if(mCartList.get(i).selected) {
                 mCartList.remove(i);
          }
      }
             mProductAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
       });      
    }
```

Here is how this works. It's a 4 tab list with different items in each tab, 3 of which or products. Customer clicks on the item and they see a description, click add to cart, then your  back at the menu. The 4th tab is a the order of what was just selected that is to populate the sms body. I have been able to pass a variable with the text "Hello World". I'm figuring the result of List mCartList can populate the sms body. I'm assuming the List can not just be inserted into the body of a forn without being converter. Let me know if you need anymore info. I'm not a programmer, I have seen similar but nothing that doesn't work without writing other files I got from a tutorial. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the products are added to your mCartList, it's just a matter of concatenating the String output of the Products together as follows:

```
orderButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:1234567890");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            for(Product p : mCartList){
                builder.append(p.toString());
                builder.append('\n');
            }

            intent.putExtra("sms_body", builder.toString()); 
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

make sure your Product has a toString() method defined as follows (example Product guess):

```
public class Product{
    String productName;

    public String toString(){
        return productName;
    }
}
```

Comment: You did it thank you. I'm not getting the title I get com.android.blah.Product@453bc2a0 which is the memory addresses it remembers it aso I just need to play around. I appreciate the quick response. You did what I asked. I got 23 hours to award it.

Comment: Glad I could help.  If you are getting the memory address, remember to define the toString() method on the Product.  That should override Object.toString(), which outputs the memory address.

Comment: I figured it out all by  myself.. Just kidding. Thank you. I made an app, now I can go back to being a graphic designer. Vote for johncarl 2032. I'll award it once it lets me.